# DOM XML in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, xml, dom, suse

I am processing XML files in PHP 5.6 running in SUSE 11, which glic library is version 2.11. However, the RPM of PHP 5.6 DOM requires glibc library version 2.14.

Are there any alternative from installing the DOM module?

Comment: You can't compile it?  Seems like you have full access to the system.  Other than that, PHP 5.6 rpms are probably not officially supported on SuSE 11.  SuSE 11 was released in 2009, so you'd be better off either upgrading your OS or using the recommended PHP version for that distribution.

Comment: I don't want to install it by compile because it is difficult to manage the module such as uninstalling. I installed PHP5.6 by rpm too without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem by finding another PHP 5.6 rpm package which does not depend on glibc 2.14. The file is **php5-5.6.18-325.1.x86_64.rpm** and can be downloaded from the official website http://software.opensuse.org/ . Thanks.